# Primefaces MultiSelectListBox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to get SelectItemGroup values so that the entire trace of the SelectItem is contained in the value passed to the bean from the view? I have two SelectItemGroups and one SelectItem, but need the values contained in the SelectItemGroups as well.

Comment: [tour], [ask], http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and pick the relevant ones on http://idownvotedbecau.se/

Comment: So effectively you want to send all children of a group (2 groups and one item)?

Comment: Precisely. I was hoping there was a Javascript hack for it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem this is possible but would be a great feature. I used a Datatable instead but the MultiListBox would have been more elegant.